# self-signed SSL certificate error: certificate has invalid digital signature

Tags: windows-7, https, ssl-certificate, netsh

I have a c# program and part of it creates a self-signed certificate.

The problem is when i try to import the certificate in MMC it says "This certificate has an invalid digital signature."

And when i try to add this certificate through command prompt using netsh http add it says:

SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

I've tried all suggestions from other sites, still no luck.

By the way, my machine is running in Windows7-64bit.